# Taking Items of varying types from file and adding them to an array

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm currently working on a lab that needs to keep inventory for a hardware store in a variety of ways. One of the ways is to put the information into an array. There is a list of tools that are given that each have a Record number, name, quantity, and cost. I figured that the best way to go about doing this is to put the information into a text file and add it into the array from there, but I am stuck on how to do so. So far I am able to manually add each item but that is very tedious and wont be easy to work with.

```
struct node {
    int recordNum; 
    char toolName[20]; 
    int quantity; 
    double toolCost; 

    node* next; 
};

void unsortedArray() {
    ifstream toolsFile("Tools.txt");
    const int MAX = 100;
    node unsortedArr[MAX];

    unsortedArr[0].recordNum = 68;
    strcpy_s(unsortedArr[0].toolName, "Screwdriver");
    unsortedArr[0].quantity = 106;
    unsortedArr[0].toolCost = 6.99;
}
```

I'm using a struct node as I later have to use linked lists. Here is the .txt file that has the information for each of the products.

```
68  Screwdriver     106     6.99
17  Hammer          76      11.99
56  Power saw       18      99.99
3   Electric Sander 7       57
83  Wrench          34      7.5
24  Jig Saw         21      11
39  Lawn mower      3       79.5
77  Sledge hammer   11      21.5
```

If there is a way to do this that doesn't involve the text file that works perfectly fine as well. I'm new to C++ and this is just what came to mind first.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gather you would like to store values from a text file into an array. If so,
you would want to start by reading each line from the file. Next, split the line into each data field. Then append to the text file and repeat.

To read each line, I used a string to hold the line being read
Next, the line is split every time a character is seen. I used a ';' to separate values.
For example, the first line of your file would read:

```
68;Screwdriver;106;6.99
```

The splitting procedure then returns a vector of strings. This holds, in order:
record number, name, quantity and price.
The numbers that are integers and doubles need to be converted from strings, so
two functions cast them.
Finally, the values are stored in the index specified. For eg, after the program runs, index 68 of the array would hold 68, Screwdriver, 106, 6.99.

Here is the working solution

Note, to simplify the storage method a bit, I have changed tool name to a string. Feel free to change it back if need be

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

std::vector<std::string> split(std::string strToSplit, char delimeter) {
    std::stringstream ss(strToSplit);
    std::string item;
    std::vector<std::string> splittedStrings;
    while (std::getline(ss, item, delimeter)) {
        splittedStrings.push_back(item);
    }
    return splittedStrings;
}

struct node {
    int recordNum;
    std::string toolName; // Changed this as string was already used elsewhere
    int quantity;
    double toolCost;

    node* next;
};


int main() {
    node node_array[100];
    int index;

    std::ifstream tool_file;
    tool_file.open("Text.txt"); //The record file

    std::string line;
    std::vector<std::string> split_line;

    while (std::getline(tool_file, line)) { //Repeat for each line of file

        split_line = split(line, ';'); // Split each line into its components
        index = stoi(split_line[0]); // Convert record num into an int

        node_array[index].toolName = split_line[1];  // Save values into index
        node_array[index].quantity = stoi(split_line[2]);
        node_array[index].toolCost = stod(split_line[3]);
        
    }
    tool_file.close();
    
}
```

Comment: c++ standard has built in `stoi` and `stod` to convert from `string` to `int` and to `double`.

Comment: Thanks for that, completely blanked on the builtin functions. Fixed now.